# DateTimeOffsetAdapter interfering with WCF serialization of DateTimeOffset objects

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization, datetimeoffset

I have a WCF service reference (= client proxy) generated by Visual Studio 2008 (.net 3.5 sp1). The generated code contains a data contract with DateTimeOffset properties so naturally VS decorated it with KnowTypeAttribute(System.DateTimeOffset).

Whenever I invoke a WCF operation that returns the above mentioned data contract, I get the following exception:

> Type 'System.DateTimeOffset' cannot be
>   added to list of known types since
>   another type 
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.DateTimeOffsetAdapter'
>   with the same data contract name 
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System:DateTimeOffset'
>   is already present

I understand that DateTimeOffsetAdapter is a struct in System.Runtime.Serialization that is used when serializing DateTimeOffset objects. So why does it cause this exception and how can this be fixed or avoided?

Comment: Sucks this was never answered.

Comment: Does anybody know the answer?

Comment: @urig: What have you done to solve this problem?

Comment: @billybob Most likely I've used a different type than DateTimeOffset - It's been too long for me to remember. But had I found a good solution I would have posted it here. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the issue seemed to stem from having .Net 4 installed **prior** to adding IIS as a feature to Windows 7.

A colleague and I fixed the issue by opening an elevated (Run As Administrator) command prompt. Then ran the following:

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: There's an error in the path: Should be `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why. But to solve the problem try to migrate your project to .NET Framework version 4